# lcov appears to process .gcda files in a single process. I have many cores and I'd like to use them for this processing. How?

Tags: makefile, gcov, lcov

If I run:

```
lcov --output-file $(BUILD_DIR)/coverage_all.info --capture --directory $(BUILD_DIR)
```

It appears to process each .gcda file one at a time instead of taking advantage of all my cores.  Is it possible to rewrite this step so that I can produce the `coverage_all.info` file while using all my cores?

I'm thinking of something that I would put in a make file and run make with the `-j` option so it would spawn multiple jobs, each recording their results in a different file.  Then when all the jobs complete, I would merge them together, perhaps using the `lcov --add-tracefile` option.

Does anyone know how to do something like this?